# Strange Code Analysis Problem About TFS 2010 Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I have got strange problems in the last few days. Today's strange problem is about Code Analysis and TFS 2010 Builds.

After we had upgraded our TFS from 2008 to 2010, we then upgraded our solutions from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010.  There were no errors while upgrading, but we saw strange things about code analysis.

Shortly the problem is, FxCop results differ by running automatically from tfs 2010 build or running manually from command prompt.  Even though they are both using the same command parameters and values.

For example i̇f i run FxCop in the TFS build, I get 7 errors, but i̇f I run FxCop by command prompt using the command I see in the  build log, I get 133 errors.

What could cause these differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

It was about CustomDictionary path.

I deleted FXCop\CustomDictionary.xml for test and forget. I replaced CustomDictionary and everything became normal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your VS and command line analysis runs are using the same rule sets?

Comment: Yes, because i copied fxcop command from tfs build log and pasted to command line. so, they are same...

Comment: i post as answer because of length